# Uncertain of this Swift struct syntax with closure

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I'm stumped by a bit of Swift struct syntax.

For a regular struct, I understand how to define and initialize it.

```swift
struct Thing {
    let name: String
}

let aThing = Thing(name: "The Name")
```

But I was reading a bit about functional programming and came across this syntax and what stumped me most was the initialization.

```swift
struct Effect<T> {
    let run: (@escaping (T) -> Void) -> Void
}

// What is "callback" here? How does this work?
let anIntInTwoSeconds = Effect<Int> { callback in
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        callback(42)
    }
}

anIntInTwoSeconds.run { theInt in
    print(theInt)
}
```

If I were to see that with a "normal" initializer, I would understand it, but what is happening on this line? What is this syntax called so I can research it further?

```swift
let anIntInTwoSeconds = Effect<Int> { callback in
```

Comment: Do you know about [trailing closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)?

Comment: It is exactly the same syntax as the line `anIntInTwoSeconds.run { theInt in`. Do you understand that line?

Comment: Let me verify that I do understand the .run line ...

run is a function that returns Void. It accepts a function. That function accepts an Int and returns Void. So that line says, hey run, execute this function.

If that's correct, I'm still fuzzy on the other line.

Comment: I'd phrase that differently. Run is a property that holds a closure. (an anonymous function.) The run closure's parameter is a Generic, which means that the parameter passed to the closure depends on the type used to create the Effect struct.

Comment: (So an `Effect<Int>` struct's run parameter is a closure of type `(Int) -> Void`. An `Effect<String>` struct's run parameter would be of type `(String) -> Void`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration for the `Effect type`

```
struct Effect<T> {
```

Defines Effect as using a Generic type T. So you can create Effect objects that work on different types.

The line

```
let anIntInTwoSeconds = Effect<Int> { callback in
```

Creates an Effect object that operates on Ints, and assigns it to the variable `anIntInTwoSeconds`.

The `{ callback in` part defines the closure for the Effect object. That declaration could be rewritten like this:

```
let anIntInTwoSeconds = Effect<Int>(run: { callback in
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        callback(42)
    }
}
)
```

You can interpret as:

'Create an instance of the Effect struct, with a `run` property that contains the closure that begins with "{ callback in"...'

(It's confusing because the run property is, itself, a closure. So we create an instance of Effect, and pass it a "run" value that's a closure.)

The "callback in" part, specifically, tells the compiler that, inside that closure, the parameter to the closure should be named "callback".

Comment: This is bending my noodle. ;-)

Comment: Does that `let anIntInTwoSeconds = Effect<Int> { callback in` syntax work because the `run` property is the only one defined on the struct?

Comment: I'm not sure, TBH. Thats a variant I haven't seen before. There's another case called "Trailing closure syntax" where when you call a function, if the last parameter is a closure, you can provide the closure outside the parens. This looks similar to that, but I'm not sure what makes it legal.

Comment: "This is bending my noodle." That sounds painful.

Comment: @DuncanC I believe it is trailing closure syntax, just on an `init`. The memberwise init will be something like `init(run: @escaping ((T) -> Void) -> Void)`, similar to how something like `VStack` is initialized without `()`. What I don't know is if a nested `@escaping` has any effect if you manually created the `init`.

Comment: It does seem to be trailing closure syntax on the init function. I asked about that in another thread and Matt (one of the top contributors for things Apple) confirmed it.

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70041110/how-can-you-initialize-a-struct-with-a-closure-parameter-like-this