# How can you initialize a struct with a closure parameter like this?

Tags: swift, struct, closures

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039118/uncertain-of-this-swift-struct-syntax-with-closure/70039340?noredirect=1#comment123810935_70039340) I saw today It defines a struct `Effect` that has a property `run` that is a closure that takes a Generic parameter:

```
struct Effect<T> {
    let run: (@escaping (T) -> Void) -> Void
}
```

Then the sample code creates an instance of `Effect<Int>`, and specifies the closure for the `run` property with something that looks like trailing closure syntax:

```
let anIntInTwoSeconds = Effect<Int> { callback in
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        callback(42)
    }
}
```

What makes that legal? I would expect to need to specify the run parameter explicitly in a call to the init method:

```
let anIntInTwoSeconds = Effect<Int>(run: { callback in
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        callback(42)
    }
}
)
```

Either version compiles and works. What in Swift makes that first version legal? I couldn't figure out how to frame the question so that I could search for an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works just like any function whose last parameter is a function. Trailing closure syntax is trailing closure syntax. The fact that the function is an initializer changes nothing.

So let me build up to it in stages. You know you can say:

```
func myfunc(whatever: () -> ()) {}
myfunc {}
```

Okay, but now let's make it a static method:

```
struct S {
    static func myfunc(whatever: () -> ()) {}
}
S.myfunc {}
```

OK, but `init` *is* a static method — it's just a static method whose name you are allowed to omit:

```
struct S {
    let whatever: () -> ()
}
S {} // meaning S.init {}
```

Comment: Huh. It never occurred to me that you could use trailing closure syntax in a call to an initializer, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: Lots and lots and lots of built-in library types use this, I'm amazed you've never noticed until now. And of course SwiftUI is utterly dependent on this sort of thing.

Comment: Ok, I've never quite understood SwiftUI's syntax for creating View objects, but now it makes perfect sense. I was being obtuse.